# Spring-Data Project is not receiving my Get/Post "404 not found"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc

I finished creating a simple Spring-boot project in which I can enter users and through the Get command it returns me the name (from a list of identical names) with the oldest entry date. Unfortunately, every time I ask for Get it returns this **ERROR**:

```
D:\>curl -G  localhost:8080/demo/first?=Biagio
{"timestamp":"2020-10-04T22:46:35.996+00:00","status":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"","path":"/demo/first"}
```

And to each of my POST / Add requests like this **ERROR**:

```
D:\>curl localhost:8080/demo/add -d name=Giovanni -d email=giovanni@gmail.com -d surname=Jackie
{"timestamp":"2020-10-04T22:40:51.928+00:00","status":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"","path":"/demo/add"}
```

Below I enter the interested parties of my project to try to get something out of it, because I have been stuck for days now

**AccessingDataMysqlApplication.java**

```
package com.example.accessingdatamysql;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;


@SpringBootApplication
public class AccessingDataMysqlApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(AccessingDataMysqlApplication.class, args);
  }

}
```

**MainController.java**

```
package com.example.accessingdatamysql.rest;

import javax.persistence.NoResultException;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.example.accessingdatamysql.model.UserDto;
import com.example.accessingdatamysql.service.UserService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/demo")
public class MainController {

@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@Transactional
//@RequestMapping(value = "/add/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@PostMapping(path="/demo/add")
public String addNewUser(@PathVariable("name") String name, @PathVariable("email") String email,
@PathVariable("surname") String surname) {

UserDto n = new UserDto();
n.setName(name);
n.setSurname(surname);
n.setEmail(email);
userService.create(n);
return "User Saved in DB";
}

@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
//@RequestMapping(value = "/fetchUser/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@GetMapping("/demo/first")
public ResponseEntity<UserDto> fetchUser(@PathVariable("name") String name) {
System.out.println(name);

try {
UserDto namefound = userService.findFirstByName(name);
System.out.println("Name found");
ResponseEntity<UserDto> user = new ResponseEntity<UserDto>(namefound, HttpStatus.OK);
return user;
} catch(NoResultException ne) {
System.out.println("User not found");
return new ResponseEntity("User not found with name : " + name, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
}

}
}
```

**UserService.java**

```
package com.example.accessingdatamysql.service;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.example.accessingdatamysql.model.UserDto;
@Service
public interface UserService {

    UserDto findFirstByName(String name);
    
    void create(UserDto user);
        
}
```

**UserServiceImpl.java**

```
package com.example.accessingdatamysql.service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.example.accessingdatamysql.model.UserDto;
import com.example.accessingdatamysql.model.UserEntity;
import com.example.accessingdatamysql.repo.UserRepository;
import com.example.accessingdatamysql.util.UserMapper;

@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
    
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    UserMapper mapper;

    @Override
    public UserDto findFirstByName(String name) {
        UserEntity entity = userRepository.findFirstByName(name);
        return mapper.toDtoMapper(entity);
    }

    @Override
    public void create(UserDto user) {
        UserEntity entity = mapper.toEntityMapper(user);
        userRepository.create(entity);
    }

}
```

**UserMapper.java**

```
package com.example.accessingdatamysql.util;

import org.mapstruct.Mapper;

import com.example.accessingdatamysql.model.UserDto;
import com.example.accessingdatamysql.model.UserEntity;



@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface UserMapper {   
    
    public UserEntity toEntityMapper (UserDto user);    
    public UserDto toDtoMapper (UserEntity userEntity);
    
}
```

**UserRepository.java**

```
package com.example.accessingdatamysql.repo;


import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.example.accessingdatamysql.model.UserEntity;


@Repository
public interface UserRepository {
    UserEntity findFirstByName(String name);
    void create(UserEntity entity);
    
}
```

**UserRepositoryImpl.java**

```
package com.example.accessingdatamysql.service;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Root;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.example.accessingdatamysql.model.UserEntity;
import com.example.accessingdatamysql.repo.UserRepository;

@Component
public class UserRepositoryImpl implements UserRepository {

    private final EntityManager em;

    public UserRepositoryImpl(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.em = entityManager;
    }

    @Override
    public UserEntity findFirstByName(String name) {
        CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<UserEntity> criteria = builder.createQuery(UserEntity.class);
        Root<UserEntity> root = criteria.from(UserEntity.class);
        criteria.select(root).where(builder.equal(root.get("name"), name));
        criteria.orderBy(builder.asc(root.get("timestamp")));
        TypedQuery<UserEntity> query = em.createQuery(criteria).setMaxResults(1);
        return query.getSingleResult();

    }

    @Override
//  per la creazione//
    public void create(UserEntity entity) {
        em.persist(entity);
    }

}
```

**UserDto.java**

```
package com.example.accessingdatamysql.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Timestamp;

public class UserDto implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7621330660870602403L;
    /**
     * 
     */

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Timestamp getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(Timestamp timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    private Timestamp timestamp;
    private String email;
    private String surname;

}
```

If you need I can also insert User.java and the pom, but the pom has no problems as the dependencies are all correct.

Comment: The way you've setup your controller, the expected paths are `/demo/demo/add` and `/demo/demo/first`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an additional `demo` in your path descriptions for GET and POST methods, you should remove it:

```
@GetMapping("/demo/first")

@PostMapping(path = "/demo/first")
```

It should be :

```
@GetMapping("/first")

@PostMapping(path = "/first")
```

This because you have already defined `demo` in the `RequestMapping` annotation in the class level.